# SElinux: How to change to permissive mode without a reboot?

Tags: linux, selinux

I need to change selinux to "permissive mode" on a production server without a reboot, but setenforce wont let me do it(as a root), it always prints "setenforce: SELinux is disabled" 
What i'm doing wrong?

```
[root@server3 ~]# setenforce 0
setenforce: SELinux is disabled
[root@server3 ~]# setenforce 1
setenforce: SELinux is disabled
[root@server3 ~]# setenforce Permissive
setenforce: SELinux is disabled
[root@server3 ~]# getenforce
Disabled
```

Comment: Might have something to do with SELinux hooking into the kernel? Sounds plausible to me, perhaps someone will know for sure.

Comment: If selinux is disabled at boot the machine will have to be reoboted in order to enable it again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`setenforce` can only be used to *change* the mode SELinux is running in. It *cannot* be used to enable SELinux.

Answer (score 4):

So, SELinux must first be enabled as follow:

```
sudo nano /etc/selinux/config
```

then change

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

into

```
SELINUX=permissive
```

and reboot.

After reboot, you should have

```
# getenforce
Permissive
```

Comment: Notice the Q states w/o a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

setenforce 0 (Does not require reboot) and then check sestatus